# PostgreSQL create a table by taking elements from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in postgresql which are the following:

```
             table1
Names(can have duplicates)        Codes 
|                                 |
Name1                             code1
Name2                             code2
Name3                             code3
Name1                             code4
Name2                             code5
Name1                             code5
           table2
Codes                             Hours
|                                 |
code1                             12
code2                             4
code3                             1
code4                             5
code5                             2
```

So basically codes are for projects that people have worked on. Table1 has a persons name and the project he has worked on. A person can have worked on more than 1 projects. Table2 has the project's code and hours it took to complete. 2 different people can have worked on the same project. I wanna find out how many hours has each person worked totally. So i wanna create a table that has 2 columns: 1. Names(non duplicate) 2. total hours. Can I avoid making temporary tables or using loop statements to get the result I want?

Comment: You have `Name2 | code2` twice in table1, why? is this typo?

Comment: yes it is I am gonna change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

```
select Names, sum(Hours)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.Codes = t2.Codes
group by Names
;
```